# Why can't my C code find my Java functions?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My application makes calls to a native library, and then within the native library, makes calls back to the Java code. I have the calls TO the native library working correctly ( I'm pretty sure ), but not its telling me that it can't find the Java functions when trying to call them from the C file.

The application doesn't even crash, there is no pop up telling me it closed unexpectedly, it just flashes a black screen and nothing happens.

The code I am trying to reproduce was originally made in C for Palm Pilot, and is being transferred to an Android device. This is the original call in C I am trying to duplicate...

```
InitRelay(Changeit,getit,putit,flushit,delayit);
```

The parameters in the call above are function names, the functions are here below:

```
void Changeit(WORD baud){
    ChangeRate(baud);
}

extern Boolean ChangeRate(UInt32 baud)
{...}

Int16 getit(UInt16 t) {...}

void putit( BYTE p ) {...}

void flushit(void){...}

extern void delayit( UInt16 wait ) {...}
```

This is InitRelay shown in my `.c` file:

```
BYTE __stdcall InitRelay(fp_setbaud _setbaud, fp_get _get, fp_put _put, fp_flush _flush, fp_delay _delay){

    RelayAPI_SetBaud=_setbaud;
    RelayAPI_get=_get;
    RelayAPI_put=_put;
    RelayAPI_flush=_flush;
    RelayAPI_delay=_delay;
    ....
}
```

The parameters shown in above are typedefed in my `.h` file:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_setbaud)(WORD);
typedef short (__stdcall *fp_get)(WORD);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_put)(BYTE);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_flush)(void);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_delay)(WORD);
```

The `WORD/BYTE/DWORD` types are defined in a separate `.h` file shown here:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
```

Now, in my Android code, I call a function I made called InitRelayJava(), all of my data for the application is stored in a separate class called `RelayAPIModel`. I created a nested class within that to store all of my native functions. I did this so that I can access these functions the same way no matter what Activity the application is currently in.

```
public class RelayAPIModel {
    ....
    public static class NativeCalls {
        static {
            System.loadLibrary( "RelayAPI" );
        }

        public native static byte InitRelayJava();

    public native static void FreeRelayJava();


        public static void changeItJavaWrapper( short l ) {
            mModelService.changeitJava( l );
        }

        public static void flushItJavaWrapper() {
            mModelService.flushitJava();
        }

        public static void putItJavaWrapper( byte[] p ) {
            mModelService.putitJava( p );
        }

        public static void delayItJavaWrapper( short wait ) {
            mModelService.delayitJava( wait );
        }

        public static short getItJavaWrapper( short s ) {           
            return mModelService.getitJava( s );
        }
    }
 }
```

The calls made inside the `*Wrapper` functions go to a separate class that I have to handle all of the applications bluetooth capabilities. I do not think that those are needed for this problem.

This is what InitRelayJava looks like in my C code...

```
BYTE Java_my_eti_commander_RelayAPIModel_00024NativeCalls_InitRelayJava( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj  ) {

    myEnv = (env);
    bluetoothClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass( env, obj );
    myObject = obj;

    changeID = (*myEnv)->GetMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "changeitJavaWrapper", "(S)V"  );
    getID    = (*myEnv)->GetMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "getitJavaWrapper"   , "(S)S"   );
    putID    = (*myEnv)->GetMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "putitJavaWrapper"   , "(B)V" );
    flushID  = (*myEnv)->GetMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "flushitJavaWrapper" , "()V"   );
    delayID  = (*myEnv)->GetMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "delayitJavaWrapper" , "(S)V"  );
...
}
```

This is the LogCat I am receiving...

```
08-02 10:27:32.406: D/dalvikvm(28376): Trying to load lib /data/data/my.eti.commander/lib/libRelayAPI.so 0x40515430
08-02 10:27:32.406: D/dalvikvm(28376): Added shared lib /data/data/my.eti.commander/lib/libRelayAPI.so 0x40515430
08-02 10:27:32.406: D/dalvikvm(28376): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/my.eti.commander/lib/libRelayAPI.so 0x40515430, skipping init
08-02 10:27:32.406: D/dalvikvm(28376): GetMethodID: method not found: Lmy/eti/commander/RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls;.changeitJavaWrapper:(S)V
08-02 10:27:32.413: D/dalvikvm(28376): GetMethodID: method not found: Lmy/eti/commander/RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls;.getitJavaWrapper:(S)S
08-02 10:27:32.413: E/dalvikvm(28376): Class lookup Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError; attempted while exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError; pending
```

Comment: Does this compile ? Coz there s a space in the static class's name... 'Native Class'

Comment: Remove space from your static inner class name

Comment: that was atypo in the SO quetsion, its not like that in my code.

Comment: There is no space in the class name in my code. I typed all of the code above into the SO question without copy/paste. The typo was in my writing of the question, in my code it is written properly and there is no syntax error

Comment: @userSeven7s any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InitRelayJava` is a static method - that means your second parameter (`obj`) is a class object pointer, not a `this` pointer. So get rid of the following line:

```
bluetoothClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass( env, obj );
```

and instead pass `obj` to GetMethodID(), like this:

```
changeID = (*myEnv)->GetMethodID( myEnv, obj, "changeitJavaWrapper", "(I)Z"  );
```

EDIT: also, your parameter/return type signatures are wrong. Short is not the same as int, so the signature for `changeitJavaWrapper` is "(S)Z", for `getitJavaWrapper` is "()I" as it takes no parameters and returns an int. Be more careful please; it does not take an advanced knowledge of C to get those right, just some self-checking. This project of yours is inching into [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) territory.

Cheat sheet on JNI type codes [here](http://dev.kanngard.net/Permalinks/ID_20050509144235.html).

Let me try and anticipate your next question - you cannot call those methods. Of course you cannot, it's not possible to call a nonstatic method from a static one. Your Java callbacks are all nonstatic, while the native method is static. Either make them static, or make the native method nonstatic and insert the `GetObjectClass` back.

EDIT2: so you changed your Java methods to static without telling. Now instead of `(*env)->GetMethodID()` you need to call `(*env)->GetStaticMethodID()` to get the method ID. Same parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, my LogCat did change a bit after the edit though. Check the edit if you find the time. Thanks.

Comment: See the edit. AND CHECK FOR THOSE THINGS YOURSELF BEFORE YOU ASK.

Comment: I did check for those, sorry. I had made those signatures a week or so ago and thought that they matched.

Comment: So did you fix the signatures? Did it help?

Comment: No it did not help. I am going to poke around more before I ask any more questions. Your article up there made me feel like a piece of garbage. I have become very discouraged with this project as I feel its very over my head, and I admit I have gotten lazy with certain things. But relax, no need to jump down my throat so fast, I AM trying to learn. Also, it says you've been coding since '93. I was born in '92. You've been coding for 19 years, I've been coding for not even 2.

Comment: Don't get discouraged, we all had to start somewhere. Just rethink your problem solving strategy, specifically the relative priority of searching and reading vs. asking online. That said - is the "method not found" error message still the same?

Comment: For the record, the crushing sense of utter impotence is a fairly regular state of mind in our profession. The trick it channeling it into a nice productive rage.

Comment: Well then, edit the question, post the latest code and the latest log. It's OK to replace the old ones, don't add in the bottom.

Comment: Replaced it. Added what I thought would be needed.

Comment: Replace `GetMethodID` calls with `GetStaticMethodID`. When you change the Java method, you have to change the C access to it accordingly.

Comment: That got rid of the first two errors in my LogCat, I'll try to find the last on my own. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signatures are wrong. Use `javap -s classname` to get the signatures of the class, for example: `javap -s java.lang.String`.
You can find `javap` in your local JDK.